# Adding insulation to roof rafters, air gap and eaves

Tags: insulation, roof

I'm adding insulation to a small shed/garage which has the same roof construction method as the main house. Gable roof, slate tiles, batons, felt and rafters.

I'm adding 50mm insulation boards in between rafters which are 100mm deep. So leaving 50mm air gap.

There's open eaves at one wall only. On the other side there's no gap or airflow. Not sure if that's standard or both sides usually have open eaves.

If there's open eaves at one side, it is OK to install the insulation and assume that the air will circulate fully from one side to the other, or should air be able to circulate from both sides?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I wouldn't fill the rafter cavity right up to the ridge, I'd stop short, continue the insulation board horizontally, then continue down the other side of the roof meaning there would be at a continuous air gap from the open eave at one side to the bottom of the roof on the other side,

Comment: [IRC R806](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch08_SecR806) uses the term "cross ventilation" for this. If you intend to enclose each rafter cavity with some sort of paneling, then you need a vent at both ends of each rafter cavity. Instead of a ridge vent, you can do some sort of shared cavity below the ridge and above a patch of ceiling. Collar ties are handy if you've got them. Otherwise, consider an [unvented system](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch08_SecR806.5).

Comment: Post-edit, you effectively have really long rafter cavities. Cross ventilation would require a vent at both soffits for each rafter cavity.